# É possível inserir e remover ao mesmo tempo na mesma página php?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Boas, neste momento estou a fazer um projeto com html, php e mysql e estou com um pequeno problema agora.

Indo mais direto ao assunto:
Supondo que eu tenho duas tabelas: não confirmados e confirmados, e o que eu quero é, na página de php conseguir passar os dados da tabela não confirmados para a confirmados, mas quando passar os dados para a tabela confirmados eu queria que esse registo desaparecesse da tabela não confirmados. (neste caso a tabela não confirmados chama-se "hospede").

Desculpem a forma que eu arranjei para tentar explicar, caso não percebam algo, digam que eu tento me explicar melhor.

```
<?php

include ('ligar.php');
$sql = "select * from hospede";
$cod_hospede=$_GET['cod_hospede'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO confirmados SELECT * FROM hospede WHERE cod_hospede = '$cod_hospede'";


$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if ($result)
echo "<br><br>Dados registados com sucesso!";
else
echo "Erro ao tentar registar dados na base de dados!";
?>
<br>
<a href="confirmados.php">voltar</a>
```

Comment: Com o seu código ele já insere? Se sim, basta fazer o delete após. Faça isso dentro de uma transação para não ter problemas futuros.

Comment: Sim, ele insere e de facto vai para a outra tabela, mas eu quero que apague da tabela não confirmados. Eu já tentei por o delete mas deu-me erro (neste caso, não foi para a outra tabela e foi removido simplesmente).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim, é possível. Crie duas consultas

```
$insert_sql = "INSERT INTO confirmados SELECT * FROM hospede WHERE cod_hospede = '$cod_hospede'";
$result1 = mysqli_query($con, $insert_sql);

$delete_sql = "DELETE from hospede WHERE cod_hospede = '$cod_hospede'";
$result2 = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

Alternativamente vc poderia utilizar transações, tanto com o mysqli quanto com PDO.

Usando mysqli:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "dbname");

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}
try{
   $mysqli->begin_transaction(MYSQLI_TRANS_START_READ_ONLY);

   $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO confirmados SELECT * FROM hospede WHERE cod_hospede = '$cod_hospede'");
   $mysqli->query("DELETE from hospede WHERE cod_hospede = '$cod_hospede'");

   $mysqli->commit(); 
} catch (Exception $e) {
// Exceção lançada, rollback na transação
   $db->rollback();
}
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: Consegui fazer o que pretendia com ajuda do seu primeiro argumento, muito obrigado a si e a todos os que responderam para ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Basta você agora jogar o código para remover da tabela que você quer remover

```
$sql2 = DELETE FROM hospede WHERE cod_hospede = '$cod_hospede'";
$result2 = mysqli_query($con, $sql2);
```

Mas dê uma estudada em Transações do Mysql, isso garante que os dois comandos SQL sejam executados, ou então nenhum dos dois... ajuda a garantir que não vai perder nenhum dado...